# How to lag by a specific unit of time?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a tibble that may have irregular timestamps.  I'd like to lag another column based on regular lags of the timestamp, like only pick a value that is offset by 1 day, or 3 hours, etc.  If there is no corresponding timestamp for the given lag, returning an NA is fine.

I have a function below for the following solution, but I am wondering if `{lubridate}` or some other package has a more tested solution than a hand-rolled one that I propose below.  I think the below will suffice, but I'd like to know if there is a canonical solution from a well-known package.  Or a better way to to this.  If not, my googling has failed me, and at least this solution is in SO.

Here is my proposed solution.

```r
library(lubridate)
#> Loading required package: timechange
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
# Make a function that lags by a given unit of time, and a value for that unit
# of time.
#   ts: vector of timestamps
#   v: vector of values associated with ts.  Same length as ts.
#   unit: the unit we will be lagging by, like "hour" or "day".
#   unit_val: amount that we can lag by in terms of the unit.  Can be positive or negative.
lag_ts <- function(ts, v, unit, unit_val=1) {
    lookup_df <-
       tibble(ts, v, ts_lag = ts + do.call(unit, list(unit_val)))
    lookup_df |>
        select(ts) |>
        left_join(lookup_df |> select(ts=ts_lag, v)
                  , "ts") |>
        pull("v")
}

#;; Try lagging by days
tibble(ts=ymd_hms("2023-04-12T00:00:00") + hours(seq(1,48,8))
       , v=lag_ts(ymd_hms("2023-04-12T00:00:00") + hours(seq(1,48,8))
                  , 1:6
                  , "days"
                  , 1)) |>
    print()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   ts                      v
#>   <dttm>              <int>
#> 1 2023-04-12 01:00:00    NA
#> 2 2023-04-12 09:00:00    NA
#> 3 2023-04-12 17:00:00    NA
#> 4 2023-04-13 01:00:00     1
#> 5 2023-04-13 09:00:00     2
#> 6 2023-04-13 17:00:00     3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>